# If $G$ is a simple $f$ an homomorphism, and $A\lhd H$ is such that $[H:A]=2$, show $f(G) \subset A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

I'm stuck with the following problem. Can someone help me by providing a hint?

Suppose $G$ is simple and let $f$ be an homomorphism between $G \to H$. If $\#G\ne2$, $A\lhd H$, and $[H:A]=2$. Then $\text{Im}f$ is a subgroup of $A$.

I know that the kernel of the homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $G$ so either is the trivial subgroup or the entire group. The last case is trivial, because everything is send to $1$ in $H$, and clearly the trivial group is a subgroup of the $A$.The case when the kernel is trivial is my problem. Here we can conclude that the orden of the image is not two, because is the same as $G$ (is one to one) and also divides the orden of $H$, i.e., $\#H=[H:A]\#A=2\#A$ i.e., the image divides the even number. But from here I'm not sure of how proceed,  any idea?

---

EDIT
 A is normal and so its inverse image is a subgroup and in this case in not too difficult to show that is also normal, since is en $G$ is either the trivial subgroup or the entire group.  The idea is to show that it must to have the entire group. If not, $f^{-1}=\{1\}$ but from here i don't know how to get the contradiction. any idea of how to eliminate the possibility of $f^{-1}={1}$

Comment: @blue ups a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the composition
$$
G\xrightarrow{f} H\xrightarrow{\pi}H/A.
$$

Now $K:=\ker(\pi\circ f)\leq G$ is normal as the kernel of a group homomorphism, so either $K=G$, or $K=\{e\}$, since $G$ is simple. If $K=G$, then $f(G)\subseteq\ker\pi=A$, and you're done.

If $K=\{e\}$, then $\pi\circ f$ is an injection of $G\hookrightarrow H/A$. But $[H:A]=2$, so $|G|\leq 2$. By hypothesis, $|G|\neq 2$, so $|G|=1$. Then $G$ is trivial, and it follows $f(G)\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3):

$f^{-1}(A)$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index at most $2$. Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: I´m not sure how to prove that it has an index of at most $2$, in this case I think that we have to show that is exactly 1. COuld you please explain with more detail( sorry for being annoying)?

Comment: I know that A is normal and so its inverse image is a subgroup and in this case in not too difficult to show that is also normal, since is in G is either the trivial subgroup or the entire group, because G is normal
The idea is to show that it has to have the entire group. If not, so $f^{-1}=\{1\}$ but from here i don't know how to get the contradiction

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Instead of examining $\ker(f)$, take $\pi:H\rightarrow H/A$ to be the projection map and apply the same reasoning you give in the question to $\ker(\pi\circ f)$.

Comment: we have again two possibilities that the $K =\ker (\pi \circ f)$ is either the entire group or just the trivial subgroup. For the first case the result is trivial so we may assume that the composition is 1-1. It follows immediately that divides the order of group and so is either 2 or 1 and by hypothesis cannot be 2. So the image is of order 1, and so $\pi f (G)\subset \{A, hA\}$ and also cannot be $A$, so the only possibility is that $\pi f (G)= hA\]$. THus its inverse image $f(G)\subset \pi^{-1}\pi f (G)= \pi^{-1}hA=\cup hA$

Comment: @JoseAntonio Good, but not quite. If $K = G$ then  we are done as you say, if $K\not = G$ then the map is injective, but also something in $G$ doesn't map to the identity in $H/A$, which only has size $2$, so the map is also surjective and $G$ has size two, a contradiction. Your argument can be made simpler by saying noting that if the image is order one, it must be the trivial subgroup, which is a case we already dealt with.